# Optimizing electric field lines drawing algorithm

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, geometry, starling-framework

I have written an algorithm which draws the electric field lines of charges i space. When there are more than one charges most of lines are curved. Since Starling does not have `drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)` kind of function.

I am using a small image of line and drawing it repeatedly on the screen to get a curved line. When all the field lines are drawn I may end up drawing thousands of small line segments on the screen. Since they have same texture this should not be a problem but still I am unsure whether it is a good idea or not.

Another technique I am thinking of is that I first make a flash sprite and draw all lines inside then draw it inside a bitmap and create a texture from that bitmap. Still I think it is not a good Idea to do this every `ENTER_FRAME` event.

```
var s:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite();
//drawing inside sprite goes here
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0xffffff);
bmd.draw(s);
var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(bmd);

var img:Image = new Image(texture);
addChild(img)
```

Comment: I think you should use the sprite-draw, just don't re-allocate the bitmap data each frame, and if possible, reuse the texture. One good thing with sprites is that you can draw a spline in there, not just a straight line, with `graphics.curveTo()` and `graphics.cubicCurveTo()`, so actual drawing will be a tad easier on the processor.

Comment: @Vesper I cant use the same texture because user will be moving charges and would want to see the changes in field lines in real time.

Comment: The point is, the more objects there are to create, the slower the app will be. If you cannot refill the texture, so be it.

Comment: What do you call the texture of a line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you are plotting smooth curves available as polylines of short sides and you want to optimize by replacing the polylines with curved primitives to compress the representation.

In the first place, you can minimize the number of line segments by means of a polyline simplification algorithm, such as Douglas-Peucker.

You can also generalize this concept by recursively splitting the polyline and choosing one or two intermediate points (one for a decompsition in *circular arcs* or *Bezier quadrics*, two for *Bezier cubics*), and checking if a deviation criterion is met or not.

You will see the number of required arcs dropping sharply.

If your curves have known angular points, make sure to force a split there, as smooth curves can't render them easily.